# High base-emitter voltage NPN transistor

Tags: bjt, npn, specifications

I just bought some NPN transistors for my project. I didn't notice before buying them, that the specification said the transistor had a emitter base voltage \$V_{be}\$ of 9 volts. Can this be true? This value is normally 0.7 Volts right?

Here are a screenshot of the specifications:

[image]

Comment: What SP said - but note this is not a value you would usually get near in most circuits - it's just a limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking of the base-emitter voltage (forward biased). The datasheet specification is for the emitter-base voltage, which is the reverse breakdown voltage (guaranteed minimum) of the emitter-base junction.

Most BJTs have a rating in the 5-9V range, a few have breakdown voltages similar to the collector-base breakdown voltage.